# AWS Cloudfront files' invalidation via REST API and Powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to invalidate an object of AWS Cloudfront distribution (just a specific file), and not sure how to produce the "signed URL" they're asking for.

My code so far is:

```
$authPref = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"
$AWSAccessKey = "xxx"
$AWSSecretKey = "xxx"
$awsDateOnly = (Get-Date).AddHours(-3).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$awsRegion = "us-east-1"
$awsServiceName = "cloudfront"
$awsRequestType = "aws4_request"

$stringToSign = $authPref + " " + $awsCallerReference + " " + $awsDateOnly + "/" + $awsRegion + "/" + $awsServiceName + "/" + $awsRequestType + " SOME_STRING_NOT_SURE_WHAT"

$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($stringToSign)
$awsHMAC = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($AWSSecretKey))
$awsHMAC = [Convert]::ToBase64String($awsHMAC)

$awsSignedToken = $authPref + " Credential=" + $AWSAccessKey + "/" + $awsDateOnly + "/" + $awsRegion + "/" + $awsServiceName + "/" + $awsRequestType + ", SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=" + $awsHMAC


#POST /2017-03-25/distribution/$awsDistributionID/invalidation HTTP/1.1
$awsDistributionID = "xxx"
$awsCallerReference = (Get-Date).AddHours(-3).ToString("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'")

$invalidateObjectXML = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InvalidationBatch xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2017-03-25/">
   <CallerReference>$awsCallerReference</CallerReference>
   <Paths>
      <Items>
         <Path>/</Path>
      </Items>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   </Paths>
</InvalidationBatch>
"@

[xml]$invalidateObjectXML = $invalidateObjectXML

$awsCFuri = "https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2017-03-25/distribution/$awsDistributionID/invalidation"

Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST `
                    -Uri $awsCFuri `
                    -Headers @{"content-type"="text/xml";
                               "x-amz-date"="$awsCallerReference";
                               "authorization"="$awsSignedToken";
                               "host"="cloudfront.amazonaws.com"} `
                    -Body $invalidateObjectXML
```

The response is:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2017-03-25/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request 
signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation 
for details.
The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/2017-03-25/distribution/blabla/invalidation
content-type:text/xml
host:cloudfront.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20170503T203650Z
content-type;host;x-amz-date
blabla'
The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20170503T203650Z
20170503/us-east-1/cloudfront/aws4_request
blabla'
</Message></Error><RequestId>123-123</RequestId></ErrorResponse>
At line:1 char:1
```

So obviously I'm doing something wrong with the signed URL string that I do, but what it is?
Couldn't find any examples on the internet (not AWS docs nor any other blog) that demonstrates it in Powershell.

Thanks

Comment: The logic is the same, regardless of your environment.  You appear to be mixing pieces of Signature Version 2 and Signature Version 4, two very different algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

AWS has developed a PowerShell module to interact with the AWS API called the [AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/). This module specifically handles request building and signing for you, so this method of calling to the raw API becomes unnecessary.

You can use this specifically to invalidate objects in a CloudFront distribution with the `New-CFInvalidation` cmdlet.  Write the paths you want to invalidate to the `Paths_Item` parameter.

### Signature:

```
New-CFInvalidation
    -DistributionId <String>
    -InvalidationBatch_CallerReference <String>
    -Paths_Item <String[]>
    -Paths_Quantity <Int32>
    -Force <SwitchParameter>
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - Invalidating Objects and Displaying Information about Invalidations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#Invalidation_Requests)
- [AWS Documentation - New-CFInvalidation Cmdlet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-CFInvalidation.html)

Comment: Thanks! I actually looked for the PS version of this command and couldn't find. Thank you